# How GridLayout items come from the Adapter(List/Image) in Android App

Tags: android, grid, adapter, listadapter, grid-layout

Is it possible to **Get the *GridLayout* items from the Adapter** in Android.

Like, The items in the GridView come from the ListAdapter associated with this view.

Please clarify my doubt.. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gridlayout doesn't have any Adapters as its not derived from AbsListView . Only GridView comes with Adapters.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, it is possible.  You don;t say what you are using to create the GridView.  Following is an example of getting the data from a cursor when you click on a cell of the grid (and putting it into an intent to call another activity):

```
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {

            Cursor c = (Cursor) (parent.getAdapter().getItem(position));
            Intent i = new Intent(mCtx, ScheduleEdit.class);
            i.putExtra("RowId", position);
            i.putExtra("Machine", c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(ScheduleDBAdapter.SCHEDULE_MACHINE)));
            i.putExtra("Priority", c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(ScheduleDBAdapter.SCHEDULE_PRIORITY)));
            i.putExtra("RunJob", c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(ScheduleDBAdapter.SCHEDULE_RUNJOB)));
            i.putExtra("Operator", c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(ScheduleDBAdapter.SCHEDULE_OPERATOR)));
            i.putExtra("NxtJob1", c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(ScheduleDBAdapter.SCHEDULE_NXTJOB1)));
            i.putExtra("NxtJob2", c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(ScheduleDBAdapter.SCHEDULE_NXTJOB2)));
            startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
        }
    });
```

Comment: The question is about gridlayouts not gridviews