# ClassCastException with a GridView

Tags: android

So I have an app that uses a GridView. I am using the support library, as the app is targeted to work with minimum API 8. So, I write this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/logotipo_high_density_vinceri_movil" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:src="@drawable/home_high_density_vinceri_movil" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/alertas_high_density_vinceri_movil" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imagelogo"
    android:layout_width="69dp"
    android:layout_height="69dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/detallenombrecamp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imagelogo"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imagelogo"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagelogo"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textocamp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imagelogo"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iconostaff"
    android:layout_width="78dp"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textocamp"
    android:src="@drawable/icono_staff_high_density_vinceri_movil" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iconofotos"
    android:layout_width="78dp"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iconostaff"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2"
    android:src="@drawable/icono_fotos_high_density_vinceri_movil" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iconovideo"
    android:layout_width="78dp"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iconofotos"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView3"
    android:src="@drawable/icono_video_high_density_vinceri_movil" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iconostats"
    android:layout_width="78dp"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iconovideo"
    android:src="@drawable/icono_estadistica_high_density_vinceri_movil" />

<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/iconostaff" >

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This Activity:
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.GridView;

```
public class DetalleCampActivity extends Activity {

private Integer[] imagenes={
        R.drawable.logo_carrefour,
        R.drawable.logo_mercedes,
        R.drawable.logo_venta_unica
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detallecamplayout);     
    GridView grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid);//This is line 26
    grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

}

}
```

And I use this adapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
int mGalleryItemBackground;
private Integer[] imagenes={
        R.drawable.logo_carrefour,
        R.drawable.logo_mercedes,
        R.drawable.logo_venta_unica
};

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    context=c;
    TypedArray attr=context.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery);
    mGalleryItemBackground=attr.getResourceId(R.styleable.Gallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
    attr.recycle();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return imagenes.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView image;
    if(convertView==null){
    image=new ImageView(context);

    image.setImageResource(imagenes[position]);
    image.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150));
    image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    image.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    }else{
        image=(ImageView) convertView;
    }
    image.setBackgroundResource(imagenes[position]);
    return image;
}

}
```

It shows no error at compilation time, but when I run the app, i have this stacktrace:

```
03-20 15:31:21.498: E/AndroidRuntime(20630): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 15:31:21.498: E/AndroidRuntime(20630): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.publidirecta.vincerientidad2/com.publidirecta.vincerientidad2.DetalleCampActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
03-20 15:31:21.498: E/AndroidRuntime(20630):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1659)
03-20 15:31:21.498: E/AndroidRuntime(20630):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
03-20 15:31:21.498: E/AndroidRuntime(20630):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
03-20 15:31:21.498: E/AndroidRuntime(20630):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
03-20 15:31:21.498: E/AndroidRuntime(20630):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-20 15:31:21.498: E/AndroidRuntime(20630):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-20 15:31:21.498: E/AndroidRuntime(20630):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
03-20 15:31:21.498: E/AndroidRuntime(20630):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 15:31:21.498: E/AndroidRuntime(20630):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-20 15:31:21.498: E/AndroidRuntime(20630):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
03-20 15:31:21.498: E/AndroidRuntime(20630):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
03-20 15:31:21.498: E/AndroidRuntime(20630):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-20 15:31:21.498: E/AndroidRuntime(20630): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
03-20 15:31:21.498: E/AndroidRuntime(20630):    at com.publidirecta.vincerientidad2.DetalleCampActivity.onCreate(DetalleCampActivity.java:26)
03-20 15:31:21.498: E/AndroidRuntime(20630):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-20 15:31:21.498: E/AndroidRuntime(20630):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
```

After wasting a lot of time trying to not obtain ClassDefNotFoundError using the support library (and not being very sure why it does not throw it now) I have this one now. Any idea how to fix it? Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you also give us your import statements for the activity?

Comment: Edited. While I was editing, I think I found it... I am importing the "normal" GridView class, instead of the support library one. Am I right?

Comment: Exactly. See my answer below.

Comment: Now that was stupid of me... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to cast the `GridLayout` to `GridView`. Since it's obvious you need a `GridView`, change the following in your XML file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/grid"
```

to:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid"
```

**Alternatively**, if you really need a `GridLayout`, change the following line in your activity:

```
GridView grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid);
```

to:

```
android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout grid = (android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.grid);
```

However, then you will get an error with your adapter, since the `GridLayout` doesn't use an adapter.

Comment: That's because GridLayouts don't use adapters (like the way LinearLayouts don't use adapters). See this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11327762/361230

Comment: But I need a GridView, so I can show the images in a grid. i need a GridView, if I am not wrong.

Comment: So use a **GridView**. It's available since API level 1, so you don't need the support library and **GridLayout** at all. Or, if your images are a finite set, use the GridLayout, but put your children inside manually.

Comment: No, I need the support Library to use a GridView. If i try to use it, without the support library, Eclipse says me it needs it.

Comment: You are confusing GridView with GridLayout. They are different. For Grid **View** you don't need the support library. See this - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html and this - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: Yes, it works now, but looks like a ListView, one on top of the another. I would like it to look like, well, a grid. And have no space between the images...

Comment: If you have further questions, please post them anew. If my answer helped you solve your problem, feel free to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks for your help and patience, Shade.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps somebody with my problem, setting the GridView this way in the layout:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

will make it look like a grid.

Answer (score 0):

if you need a GridLayout badly, do these tweaks in your activity
change this :

`GridView grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid);`

to:

`android.widget.GridLayout grid = (android.widget.GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.grid);`