# Android: Detect if user touches a view inside parent view

Tags: android, touch-event

I have 40 ImageViews inside a GridLayout, they have different colors and I want to know if user touched the desirable image or somewhere else(for example if user touched red image). How should I do that?

Comment: you want to achieve that using touch listener or click listener?

Comment: @MohammadAtif which one is better? how can I achieve that with touch listener?

Comment: clicklistener is better because touch listeners are little tricky for beginners.

Comment: can you update the xml file? may be we can help better

Answer (score 1):

Set an `OnClickListener` for each view and store the views. In `onClick` you can check the view and know what ImageView was clicked. You could also think about changing the type to `ImageButtons`!

If you have further problems with your Grid not being able to be clicked, check this out: http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/11/23/listview-tips-tricks-4-add-several-clickable-areas/

TLDR: Disable focusing of the views in your layout.

Comment: I know setting all ImageViews onClick solves the problem, but I was looking for more efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you manage your images in a collection maybe think about switching to gridview and implement an adapter with an itemClickListener. So depend on which item is clicked do you action.
[How GridLayout items come from the Adapter(List/Image) in Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309597/how-gridlayout-items-come-from-the-adapterlist-image-in-android-app)